# Subtracting NULL from a decimal (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this query here:

```
@someDecimal - (select sum(amount) from SomeTable)
```

I have similiar queries using *select sum(amount) from SomeTable* to calculate some values. Thing is, if there are no values in SomeTable, the result is NULL. Now I can use ISNULL each time I am using *select sum(amount) from SomeTable* to calculate something, but its the same thing over and over again. I was wondering if there is some way to calculate that once, set it to 0 if its NULL and use that instead. I am having this caculation in a WITH region.

```
;WITH MyWithStuff AS (.....)
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you mean all the similar queries are run separately from one another? Or are they part of one big query? If it's the latter, you could simply store the result into a variable and use that variable in the queries. But that's so obvious that in your case it must have been the former...

Answer (score 1):

this behavior is called ANSI NULLS and it can be enabled or disabled per connection, using the `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` (or `ON`). heres the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) to SQL BOL, note that MS sais there that in the future turning it off will not be supported, so `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` is the way to go.

Comment: I think setting it to off is not an option. Using ISNULL is ok, I was wondering if I can set it once and use it multipletimes and how.

Comment: it changes the way operations are made when operating with null as an argument , i.e. addition, concatenation, (see the BOL link in my reply.) it is connection wide, not server wide, and needs to be set per connection explicitly.